# Backup embedded database (H2)

Tags: spring-boot, h2, database-backups

I am creating a web app using `Spring-boot` and `Jpa`. Everything is working fine. But during testing I have to manually create the obejct instances and populate the database for each test. I was wondering if I can backup the embedded db and restore it at the beginning of each test, freeing up the clutter in my test code.

Answer (score 1):

H2 allows you to create a SQL script using [`script to`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script). Then you can run a SQL script when opening a connection by appending [`init=...`](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection) to the database URL.

Answer (score 0):

The best (and easiest way) is to use Spring embedded database + SQL scripts to preload your database. A simple way to do this is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171789/3248158).

A very good article showing the population per test (and the whole setup) is: [Setup and preload database for spring integration/functional tests](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/022-preload-database-execute-sql-spring-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot has several mechanisms for initialising a database, the simplest one is arguably [via Spring JDBC](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-intialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc). All you need to do is to create a file called `data-test.sql`(assuming your test profile is named "test") and define all the data via plain SQL inserts in there.