# Embedded Database for Junit Tests for non-spring application

Tags: java, junit, junit4, h2, embedded-database

I am looking for a embedded database which I can use in `JUnit 4.12` tests. Because of the current nature of our code base & time-lines it is not possible for us to mock the database calls. We are concerned only about Mysql database. So I am looking for some kind of Embedded database which I can initialize before our each test run & then clear it after the tests. Some what similar to what [wiremock](http://wiremock.org/) does for http server.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012292/spring-configuration-for-embedded-h2-database-for-tests) & it seems it is possible to achieve it via H2 embedded database. Most of the links I have found in the web talks about using it with Spring.

Can some one let me know

1. If it is possible to achieve the same using [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) as embedded database for Junit tests for non-spring application? If yes can someone let me know how to do this or point me to some link where this use case is explained?
2. Also is there some other tools other than H2 which I can use to achieve my goals?

Comment: I think you can use H2, but I prefer to use hsqldb for this purpose. From my best knowledge you can use any embedded java database for unit testing.

Comment: Any reason why you prefer to use hsqldb over H2 for this purpose?

Comment: Firstly I like it. Secondly I need some embedded db which can imitate some oracle-specific features in sql. And last, but not least. H2 developers lies on front page. Derby database has ODBC driver. IBM ODBC driver for DB2. Proof: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0409cline2/

Comment: @VasylMoskalov - We also decided to go ahead with hsqldb. Can you please post your comments as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use H2, but I prefer to use hsqldb for this purpose. I need some embedded db which can imitate some oracle-specific features in sql.  From my best knowledge you can use any embedded java database for unit testing.