# How to show content of local h2 database(web console)?

Tags: java, spring, orm, h2, h2db

Recently I joined a new team and here guys use h2 for stub service.

I was wondering whether I can show the content of this database using web interface. At work it is available by going to `localhost:5080`

I have a project where I use h2 database, but I cannot see the h2 web console when I hit `localhost:5080`

I tried also `localhost:8082` - it also doesn't work.

My project configuration (works successfully):

```
     <bean id="wrappedDataSource" class="net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetName" value="dataSource" />
     </bean>

     <bean id="wrappedDataSource" class="net.bull.javamelody.SpringDataSourceFactoryBean">
            <property name="targetName" value="dataSource" />
        </bean>

        <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL" />
            <property name="username" value="sa" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="sessionFactory"
              class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="wrappedDataSource"/>
            <property name="configLocation">
                <value>classpath:hibernate-test.cfg.xml</value>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
```

I have not ideas how to access to h2 web console. please help.

### P.S.

I see mentions of h2 only in `.m2` folder

### P.S.2

I noticed that web console available by `http://localhost:8082/` if replace url in configuration with:

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL" />
```

**But** it works if I already start h2(in `.m2` folder find `h2` jar file and hit double click)

If h2 is not started when I start application - i see following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dbInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    ...
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Соединение разорвано: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost"
Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-182])
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    ...
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Соединение разорвано: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost"
Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect: localhost" [90067-182]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    ...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    ...
```

I want to achieve that h2 starts if it not started when I start my application.

### P.S.3

I have tried to wrote following code:

```
Server server = null;
try {
    server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers").start();
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL", "sa", "");
 } catch (Exception e) {
    LOG.error("Error while initialize", e);
 }
```

I execute it and after I am trying to type `localhost:9092` in my browser.

At this moment downloads file. inside file the following content:

```
Version mismatch, driver version is “0” but server version is “15”
```

my h2 version 1.4.182

### P.S.4

This code works:

```
public class H2Starter extends ContextLoaderListener {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(H2Starter.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {

        startH2();
        super.contextInitialized(event);
    }

    private static void startH2() {

        try {
            Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers").start();
            Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE", "sa", "");

            Server.createWebServer().start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("cannot start H2 [{}]", e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        startH2();
    }
}
```

but I need to invoke it only when concrete spring profile active(now it works always)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Let's split the question into two parts.

Depending on how you specify the connection to H2, you'll get different operational modes.

Modes are: Embedded, In-Memory, Server.

`jdbc:h2:~/test` gives you a H2 instance in [embedded mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/cheatSheet.html).
The embedded mode has a limitation of being accessible only through the same class loader and same JVM ([proof](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes))

`jdbc:h2:mem:test` gets you an in-memory H2 instance. That is also **not** accessible from outer world.

`jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/test` will start H2 server and it will be **accessible** from outside of JVM [server mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server) but with one limitation - the server needs to be started before the connection is made.

The last limitation is causing your `Connection refused: connect: localhost"` exception.

To sum everything up:

- start the H2 server **before** you start application
- use `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/test` as connection string
- ....
- happy coding :)

**Update**

Just noticed that you want to start the server in the process of launching application.

You can do that in several ways, depending how do you start the application:

- If you're using maven / gradle it's easier for you to add some profile / task so that it gets executed before the application actually starts.
- If you have to setup everything in java, I suggest you look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183503/start-h2-database-programmatically)

**Update 2**

If connection to the local database is needed only for developing / debugging purposes I would setup everything using maven profile. Answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205126/starting-an-h2-database-server-from-maven) will solve that.

If you need access to the H2 database in production (I can hardly imagine any use-case for that) it's better to do that in spring. Mainly because the application container / environment setup is likely to be different in production (compared to development environment).

To address the question regarding if to start the server outside of Spring context or not - it all depends on the requirements.
One thing you should note is that the server should be started **before** the datasource is started (otherwise the spring context will not load)

**Update 3**

Unfortunately I'm not able to give you a working solution, but according to the JavaDocs there is a difference between TCP server and Web server.
Take a closer look to the [JavaDoc of H2 Server class](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html).

I guess you should use `Server.createWebServer()` method to create the server (the difference between TCP server and Web server is that

Another great class you could use `org.h2.tools.Console` ([JavaDoc here](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Console.html))
Just run the main method of Console and I guess that should solve everything.

Comment: If to say about spring fo you suggest to make it before starting context?

Comment: i am starting application like this: mvn clean install jetty:run

Comment: Do you understand how to start the H2 server programmatically before application starting ?

Answer (score 1):

You ought to be able to use the in-memory or file-based variants, and then in your application fire up the H2 TCP server separately, e.g. using a Spring bean (mind the semi-pseudo code and sample port):

```
@Component
class Bootstrap {
    @PostConstruct
    public void startH2TcpServer() {
         Server.createTcpServer("-tcpPort", "9123", "-tcpDaemon").start();
    }
}
```

See http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#using_server

Comment: Replaced ... with actual args

Comment: As I found out - web server should be started also

Comment: You can run the web console simply by running the h2 jar directly: java -jar h2XXX.jar

Answer (score 1):

How about changing jdbc url in configuration to include

```
AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
```

to start h2 automatically.

See [Auto mixed mode](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode)

> Multiple processes can access the same database without having to
> start the server manually. To do that, append ;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE to the
> database URL. You can use the same database URL independent of whether
> the database is already open or not. This feature doesn't work with
> in-memory databases.
>
> Use the same URL for all connections to this database. Internally, when using this mode, the
> first connection to the database is made in embedded mode, and
> additionally a server is started internally (as a daemon thread). If
> the database is already open in another process, the server mode is
> used automatically.

Comment: doesn't help. Now I see following url.            **<property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test;MODE=PostgreSQL;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE" />** and I see same error as before adding aditional suffix

Comment: @gstackoverflow I think server wasn't started. Please refer to starting H2 in server mode in Spring. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1503079/1737819